# Drag and Drop .sql scripts into SQL Management Studio 2008 does NOT work?

Tags: sql-server-2008, drag-and-drop, ssms

In SQL 2000 / Query Analyser, i used to be able to drag-n-drop T-SQL script files from Windows Explorer onto Query Analyser.

Cannot do the same in SQL 2008 / Management Studio ?

I can obviously do:
File / Open / File... 
Navigate to the file
Then Open it.

But someone please tell me there is an easier way just like in 2000 !

EDIT 16/7/10: Finally got to try on home PC, works as expected. Workplace has some restrictions (NT user policies) on a/c login. With Query Analyser, i 'Run As' another a/c and drag-drop works under logged-in user; With Management Studio, i 'Run As' another a/c and drag-drop does not work under logged-in user.

Comment: @rlb.usa: guess i can write T-SQL scripts in Notepad too :P

Answer (score 8, accepted):

This works fine for me?

It's possible that this is some sort of permissions issue - if you are running Management Studio under any sort of elevated permissions then I believe Windows will prevent drag and drop operations.

Comment: hmm.. i am running on Windows XP.. this elevated business only came in after Vista ? i will check again at home which has no restrictions. But currently at work i run both Query Analyser and Management Studio on same machine. So don't see why drag-and-drop does work with QA but not MS.

Comment: Thanks, you were spot on - i was using 'Run As' which did not occurr to me this was 'Elevated permissions'